# about NSMutabuleArray

Tags: objective-c, ruby

ruby code

```
irb(main):001:0> ary = ["a", "b", "b", "a", "b"]
irb(main):002:0> ary.uniq!
```

I want to write same code in objective-c.

Comment: If you articulate the question better, you'll get a better answer.
Also, you'll get a better reputation if you accept some of the answers you get.

Answer (score 3):

You use a NSSet to ensure uniqueness. `setWithArray` receives an array containing the objects to add to the new set. If the same object appears more than once in *anArray*, it is added only once to the returned set:

```
NSArray *arr = [[NSSet setWithArray: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"a", @"b", @"b", @"a", @"b", nil]] allObjects];
//If you want to obtain a mutable array:
NSMutableArray *mutArr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: arr];
```

*allObjects* is used to return a NSArray representation of the NSSet, and this array contains all the unique objects in the initial array.

Comment: I want to return NSMutableArray.

Comment: I edited to obtain a NSMutableArray